# tex4ht: conflict between `symbol` option in `footmisc` and `hyperref`

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Maintext\footnote{Footnote
  \phantomsection
  \label{gtag:xxx}
  }

Hyperref
\hyperref[gtag:xxx]{abcd}Something
\end{document}
```

Compile with `tex4ebook` or `htlatex`, we get

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.13 \hyperref[gtag:xxx]{abcd}
                              Something
?
```

No problem for `pdflatex`. The `symbol` option is essential: if we delete it, then it succeeds to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `symbol` option results in invalid `.aux` file, the definition of the `\fnsymbol` macro is written here instead of the current footnote number. It should be fixed with the following configuration file `footmisc.4ht`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% footmisc.4ht                          2009-05-21-09:32 %
% Copyright (C) 2004--2009       Eitan M. Gurari         %
%                                                        %
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the %
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either %
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any   %
% later version. The latest version of this license is   %
% in                                                     %
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt                %
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions %
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.                  %
%                                                        %
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".%
%                                                        %
% This Current Maintainer of this work                   %
% is Eitan M. Gurari.                                    %
%                                                        %
% If you modify this program your changing its signature %
% with a directive of the following form will be         %
% appreciated.                                           %
%            \message{signature}                         %
%                                                        %
%                             gurari@cse.ohio-state.edu  %
%                 http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\immediate\write-1{version 2009-05-21-09:32}

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\leavevmode
   \vbox{%\IgnorePar
      \leftskip0pt {\ht:everypar{}\parindent0pt\leavevmode}%
      \long\def\:tempc##1{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}%
\anc:lbl f{footnote}%
\Configure{newlabel}{\cur:th\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}{\protect\p@footmisc@footnote{\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}}
\a:footnotetext
   \o:@makefntext:{\b:footnotetext \csname a:footnotebody\endcsname
                {##1}\csname b:footnotebody\endcsname}\c:footnotetext
}%
\HLet\@makefntext\:tempc
%
      \reset@font\footnotesize
      \color@begingroup
        \@makefntext{\ignorespaces#1}%
      \color@endgroup
      \ht:special{t4ht@[}}\ht:special{t4ht@]}}

% detect if the symbol or symbol* option were used
% we can detect that by testing of \thefootnote macro

\edef\footmisc:thefootnote{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\thefootnote}}
\edef\footmisc:symbol{\unexpanded{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}
\edef\footmisc:symbolstar{\unexpanded{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}

\ifx\footmisc:thefootnote\footmisc:symbol
  \newcommand\p@footmisc@footnote[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}
\else
  \ifx\footmisc:thefootnote\footmisc:symbolstar
    \newcommand\p@footmisc@footnote[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}
  \else
    \newcommand\p@footmisc@footnote[1]{\p@footnote{#1}}
  \fi
\fi

\Hinput{footmisc}
\endinput
```

It uses the `\@footnotetext` command definition from `latex.4ht` and changes few things:

```
\long\def\:tempc##1{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}%
    \anc:lbl f{footnote}%
    \Configure{newlabel}{\cur:th\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}{\protect\p@footmisc@footnote{\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}}
```

The above code requires that the value of the `\c@footnote` counter is saved in the `.aux` file. `\Configure{newlabel}` has two parameters.

The first contains hypelink to the footnote: `{\cur:th\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}` produces something like: `<a id='x2-1001f1'></a>`.

The second argument contains the text that should be shown in the document in `\ref` command: `{\protect\p@footmisc@footnote{\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}}`.

We want to write something like `{\p@footmisc@footnote {1}}` to the `.aux` file, so we need to prevent expansion of the `\p@footmisc@footnote` command using the `\protect` command, but the footnote counter needs to be expanded.

In the last step, the `\p@footmisc@footnote` is defined, depending on the current value of `\thefootnote` command. It is redefined if the `symbol` or `symbol*` options of the Footmisc package were used. In that case, it prints the footnote symbols. It uses the numbers otherwise.

Here is a updated example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
% \usepackage[]{footmisc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}\label{sec:first}

Maintext\footnote{Footnote
  \phantomsection
  \label{gtag:xxx}
  }

  Another paragraph\footnote{another footnote\label{gtag:second}}. First footnote reference \ref{gtag:xxx}

  \lipsum[1]

Hyperref 
\hyperref[gtag:xxx]{abcd} Something. Second footnote reference \ref{gtag:second}. Reference to the chapter \ref{sec:second}.

\chapter{World}\label{sec:second}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Seemingly you forgot to add a versioning info in the comment.

Comment: @Yai0Phah yes, the correct version info will be generated from the literate sources once I update them.